# How to read *.D15 (ECG) File

Tags: python

Today I copied ECG signals from an ECG machine in *.D15 format.
I am unable to understand the format and strcuture of the files.
Kindly suggest editor to view file plus or help reading it in python, etc.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Which ECG machine? What does the file look like? Is it text or binary?